# How to add string elements in dropdown list in Windows form c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have made a external class name "Enum" then in that a internal class named "UnderGraduate"

then in that class i have made a string like this

```
 class Enum
    {
     public class UnderGraduate
        {
            public string[] EducationUG=new string[]
        {
            ("Bachelor of Arts (B.A)"),
            ("Bachelor of Arts (Bachelor of Education (B.A. B.Ed)"),
            ("Bachelor of Arts (Bachelor of Law (B.A.B.L)"),
            ("Bachelor of Arts (Bachelor of Law (B.A.LLB)"),
            ("Bachelor of Ayurvedic Medicine and Surgery (B.A.M.S)"),
            ("Bachelor of Applied Sciences (B.A.S)")
}
}
}
```

now i want to call this string in the main class and add its elements  to the one dropdownlist using for loop on SelectedIndexChange of a previous dropdownlist using coding

```
private void edulvlcb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (edulvlcb.SelectedItem.ToString() == "UnderGraduate")
            {         
                educb.Items.Clear();
                foreach (string ug in new Enum.UnderGraduate.EducationUG[])
                {
                    educb.Items.Add(new ListItem(EducationUG[name].ToString()));

                }
```

but it is showing a error that

```
An Object Reference is required for non-static field ,method or property 'Project.Enum.UnderGraduate.EducationUG'
```

Please solve this problem for me please .......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this: (do not use reserved words like Enum!)

```
class Enum1
{
    public class UnderGraduate
    {
        public static string[] EducationUG=new string[]{
            "Bachelor of Arts (B.A)",
            "Bachelor of Arts (Bachelor of Education (B.A. B.Ed)",
            "Bachelor of Arts (Bachelor of Law (B.A.B.L)",
            "Bachelor of Arts (Bachelor of Law (B.A.LLB)",
            "Bachelor of Ayurvedic Medicine and Surgery (B.A.M.S)",
            "Bachelor of Applied Sciences (B.A.S)"}
    }
}


private void edulvlcb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (edulvlcb.SelectedItem.ToString() == "UnderGraduate")
    {         
        educb.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string ug in Enum1.UnderGraduate.EducationUG)
            educb.Items.Add(ug);
    }
}
```

Comment: if (edulvlcb.SelectedItem.ToString() == "UnderGraduate")
                {
                    educb.Items.Clear();
                    foreach (string ug in Enum.EducationUG)
                        educb.Items.Add(new Enum.EducationUG[name].ToString());
              Project.Enum.EducationUG  is a field but is used like atype is the error

Comment: i have removd ListItem as it was showing error missing namespace or directory

Comment: use the exact codes i gave you above. i edited it a little and tested it and it worked.

Comment: but the acual prob occuring now is it is showing the elemnts in the list that i had deleted